# Interaction Taint and Pestilence Domain

Tags: dnd-3.5e, taint

So my Cleric has been tainted and has now 2 points of taint. Looking up the [rules](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/taint.htm) I discovered taint can be partially removed by the spell *remove disease*.

So I guess taint is considered some kind of disease, at least mechanic wise?

One of my Cleric's domains is the *Pestilence Domain* (Complete Divine, p.141),
which grants him the following power:

"Granted Power:Immunity to the effects of all diseases, 
though clerics with this power can still carry infectious 
diseases."

Does this mean my Cleric is immune against the effects of taint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Disease Immunity Isn't Taint Immunity

The granted power of the pestilence Domain (*SpC* 278) is no defense against [taint](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/taint.htm#cleansingTaint) (*UA* 181) because taint is not a [disease](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#disease), despite the 3rd-level Clr spell [*remove disease*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/removeDisease.htm) [conj] (*PH* 271) mitigating some of taint's effects.

In fact, there are many things the spell *remove disease* affects that *aren't* actual, for-reals *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* diseases, including...

- [drug addiction](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/campaigns/sanity.htm#drugAddiction) (*UA* 204),
- patches of [green slime](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/dungeons.htm#slimesMoldsAndFungi) (*DMG* 76),
- the implanted eggs of a [xill](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/xill.htm) (*MM* 259-60),
- the transformation of a creature into a [vargouille](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/vargouille.htm) (*MM* 254-5), and
- the transformation of a creature's skin because of an [aboleth's slime](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/aboleth.htm) (*MM* 8),

...but immunity to disease doesn't grant immunity to these, either.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that *taint* is a variant rule and you should ask your DM how he is using taint. By the rules written, although it can be removed by the spells given, *taint* is **not a disease**. It's also not a curse, or a loss of attributes. It's a feature on it's own.

Personally, I'd probably house rule you to be immune to some of it's effects, because they are disease symptoms, but that's just me, the rules do not say so.